# JavaFX + HSQLDB. Сборка автономного приложения

Tags: java, javafx, build, hsqldb

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** Необходимо собрать настольное javaFX приложение под Windows, которое могло бы запускаться на машине пользователя без предварительной установки Java. При этом необходимо использовать Java 11 или выше, JavaFX 14 и HSQLDB.

---

**Как я пытался решить задачу:**

- *Выбор инструментария* - Если я правильно понял, с помощью jlink можно получить собственную JVM включающую только необходимые модули. Чтобы распространять удобным для пользователей способом приложение я решил использовать jpackage (из Java 14), чтобы получить установщик своего приложения (и избавиться от консоли появляющейся при запуске приложения). Среда разработки и система сборки - IDEA + Maven. Как воспользоваться функционалом jlink и jpackage из IDEA я не разобрался, поэтому работал с ними из Windows Terminal.
- *Модульность* - jlink работает с модулями, поэтому собственное приложение я также сделал модульным. В качестве встроенной БД я выбрал HSQLDB (сперва хотел H2, но она не поддерживает модули).

---

**Что не получилось:** При вызове jlink, она жалуется на HSQLDB - *Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: hsqldb* Вроде как HSQLDB модульная, однако при просмотре содержимого jar, в котором она поставляется, я не нашел module-info.class. И как я подозреваю - собственные зависимости HSQLDB не модульные.

---

**Вопросы:**

1. Можно ли заставить проглотить jlink автоматический модуль?
2. Если нет, то что нужно сделать с hsqldb, чтобы получить полноценный модуль(модули)?
3. Возможно ли вместо полноценного включения HSQLDB как модуля, добавить HSQLDB в ресурсы проекта, подгружать его кастомным загрузчиком классов, а потом все это скормить jlink?
4. Есть ли более простые и оптимальные способы решить мою задачу?